# Retrieve Facebook Insights older than 3 months with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-insights

I am using Facebook Graph API to retrive page insights information. My issue is that I can't get the ones older than 3 months. For example if I use `/insights/page_fan_adds/day?since=2013-01-20&until=2013-04-23` is all working fine but if I use `/insights/page_fan_adds/day?since=2013-01-19&until=2013-04-23` (one day before the previous since) I receive the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation", 
    "type": "FacebookApiException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

This means is not possible to get older information from the facebook page insights or I have to do something else like for example use some permissions or use other syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook will not allow more than 89 days, but you can adjust the since/until fields to get data older than 89 days.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will return up to 93 days of insights data.  You can verify this for yourself by experimenting with the `since` and `until` fields.

If you need more than 93 days, as suggested in another answer, you'll have to modify the `since` and `until` fields to get different "windows" of data.  Note that in the data returned by Facebook, paging URLs are included for your convenience.  You can use them instead of reconstructing the URLs if you so desire.